# Some records are missing while selecting from table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to match the records having `MAX(WORKITEM_ID)` but some `PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID` are not coming though they are present in `WORKITEM` table.

[image: You can see their is records present in WORKITEM table for PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID=73641]

```
select WI.WORKITEM_ID as WORKITEMID,
       PI.PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID PIID,WS.WS_LABEL as WSNAME

from  WORKITEM WI,PROCESSINSTANCE PI,TASKASSIGNMENT_V4TA,
       SDI_WIDGET_WORKSTEP WS

where WS.WS_NAME = WI.WORKSTEP_NAME and 
      TA.PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID = PI.PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID and 
      PI.status in ('PI_ACTIVATED','PI_COMPLETED')and 
      WI.PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID = PI.PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID
      and WI.status in ('I_ASSIGNED','I_AVAILABLE')
      and WI.WORKITEM_ID = 
(select MAX(WORKITEM_ID)from (select WITEM.WORKITEM_ID from WORKITEM WITEM
 where **WITEM.PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID = WI.PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID**) as WORKITEMID)
```

Comment: Can you supply some sample data for each of these tables?  Any answer you get here will also be rewriting that old-school join syntax... just don't use it.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't state which version of SQL Server you are using, but I'll assume it is 2005 or later, and therefore, will suggest using a [CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.90).aspx) . And, as Skagalak mentioned, I've rewritten the joins.

I wasn't sure whether you wanted the max value from the whole WORKITEM table or if you wanted to group it by PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID. The example below groups the  MAX(WORKITEM_ID). If you don't want that, just remove  the GROUP BY clause from the CTE.

**CAVEAT:** *I've checked for syntax, but since I couldn't test against a data set I give no guarantees that this will give the desired results. It is merely an example of how you might want to structure the query.*

```
;WITH cte AS (SELECT MAX(WORKITEM_ID) AS max_workitem_id, PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID 
                  FROM WORKITEM
                  GROUP BY PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID
                 )
    SELECT WI.WORKITEM_ID AS WORKITEMID,
           PI.PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID PIID,WS.WS_LABEL AS WSNAME
    FROM WORKITEM AS WI
        INNER JOIN PROCESSINSTANCE AS [PI] ON WI.PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID = [PI].PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID
        INNER JOIN TASKASSIGNMENT_V4 AS TA ON TA.PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID = [PI].PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID
        INNER JOIN SDI_WIDGET_WORKSTEP AS WS ON WS.WS_NAME = WI.WORKSTEP_NAME
        INNER JOIN cte ON WI.WORKITEM_ID = cte.max_workitem_id AND cte.PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID = WI.PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID
    WHERE [PI].status IN ('PI_ACTIVATED','PI_COMPLETED')    
          AND WI.status IN ('I_ASSIGNED','I_AVAILABLE')
```

Comment: In this particular case a CTE is no more than a syntactic sugar. You could easily use a normal subselect instead of it and thereby avoid relying on the OP's using a 2005+ version. Just saying.